# Postgresql - Group by and where

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this :

```
role_menu_id |  role_id     | menu_id | menu_permission_id
38                  1           2           1               
39                  1           2           2
40                  1           2           3
41                  2           4           NULL
42                  1           2           4
```

I want to group by (role_id) and the final result like this :

```
role_menu_id |  role_id     | menu_id | menu_permission_id
42                  1           2           4
41                  2           4           NULL
```

if menu_permission_id of role_id is null, then print NULL (see : row number 41).

But, if menu_permission_id of role_id is NOT null, then get max(menu_permission_id)

How? Thanks in advance

I have no SQL query yet, because confused.

Comment: SELECT max(role_menu_id), role_id, max(menu_id), max(menu_permission_id) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY role_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you that.

Note: If 2 rows have `max(menu_permission_id)`, then the query will return row with `max(role_menu_id)`.

[SQL FIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f2d7/5)

```
select * From 
(select t.*,
row_Number() over (partition by role_id,menu_id
                   order by role_Menu_id desc) as max_menu
from table1 t) t1
where max_menu=1;
```